# Php explode and echo second element

Tags: php, module, magento2.2

I have a file that use's this code

```
<?php echo $block->getStoreName(); ?>
```

to output the following on the website

> First Second Third

However I only want to only output the Third element of the string above, **First Second** do not change they always stay the same.

> Third

I'm using this code to retrieve the Third part of the string

```
echo explode('First Second', $block->getStoreName())[1];
```

Its throwing up an error.

> Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in
>   /home/xyz/m230.xyz.com/app/code/Vendor/Siteinfo/view/frontend/templates/storename.phtml
>   on line 1

Line 1 in storename.phtml is

```
<?php echo explode('First Second', $block->getStoreName())[1]; ?>
```

I'm unsure if thats the correct way of doing it.

UPDATE - Have attempted a clearer explanation of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: please share full error you are getting

Comment: Well, following your example, `Second element Unique` doesn't contain `KOSH mArt`... so...

Comment: You write "Its throwing up an error.". But you do not tell us what that error says. _Why not?_

Comment: echo explode(' ', $block->getStoreName())[2];

Comment: try with just `explode(' ',$block->getStoreName())[2]`

Comment: `Undefined offset: 1` presumably. It's a common misconception that you should involve `explode()` for every string task in PHP.

Comment: @mario yes. Obviously it's regex that is the answer :-)

Comment: The above comment doesn't mean it.

Comment: Based on the string you provided your code should work. What is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo explode(' ', $block->getStoreName())[2];
```

Comment: Maybe you should clean it up so that it doesn't fail with an error if the string is not what OP expects

Comment: yes it is just static solution according to his question. if he needs dynamic one then he need to provides us details and logic of what he is thinking. he must be getting "Second element" part from any variable. what is the expected string can be like "First element", "Third element" like that. because if it is part of default framework then it will output string like i suggestion.

Comment: Thanks this works, without the closing ?> php tag. I dont know if that's how it should be but it works.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
// checks if string has "Unique"
if(mb_strpos($block->getStoreName(),'Unique') !== false){
    // prints "Unique"
    echo "Unique";
}
```